# In SQL How can I describe the structure of a result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I wanted to describe a table in MSSQL, I could do:

```
exec sp_columns @table_name
```

How could I do the same thing with a result set?
Say I had something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t3.ID,
t4.ID
FROM 
t2 INNER JOIN
t3 on t3.ID = t2.t3ID INNER JOIN 
t4 on t4.ID = t3.t4ID
```

and wanted to run something like

```
exec sp_columns @table_name = (SELECT DISTINCT 
t3.ID,
t4.ID
FROM 
t2 INNER JOIN
t3 on t3.ID = t2.t3ID INNER JOIN 
t4 on t4.ID = t3.t4ID 
)
```

In order to get a description of my result set.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because ultimately the query is going into a temp table and I don't want to manually figure out what it is so I can first create the temp table. It's a lot more complex than the example table I put here. If there are other techniques, I'm all eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the functionality of `sp_columns` for your adhoc resultset.

It sounds as if you're creating a temp table from this result set. Consider using `SELECT INTO` instead. You won't HAVE to know the structure.

Here's a proof of concept:

```
SELECT * INTO ##newtable 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
             t3.ID,
             t4.ID
       FROM 
       t2 INNER JOIN
       t3 on t3.ID = t2.t3ID INNER JOIN 
       t4 on t4.ID = t3.t4ID 
      ) as b

SELECT * FROM ##newtable
```

Comment: Only caveat is the table (temp or otherwise) can not exist prior to the `SELECT ... INTO` statement.